# Adding external figure using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to include figure in my `pdf` using TikZ. I used the following code but the figure disappears:

```
\documentclass[12pt,vi,twoside]{mitthesis}
\usepackage{lgrind}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
  \pgfdeclareimage{Depth}{images/Depth.jpg}

  \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \pgfuseimage{Depth}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \caption{MyCap.}
    \label{fig:Lab}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Misaki, welcome to the site! Why do you want to use a `tikzpicture` with `\pgfuseimage` to include the picture instead of simply using `\includegraphics{<file name>}`? Also, it would be great if you could edit your question to turn the code snippet into a complete compilable minimal example (so something starting from `\documentclass`), that makes it much easier to find the source of the problem.

Comment: Using ' \includegraphics{<file name>} ' makes figures look blocked or pixelized.

Comment: @Misaki if you want to avoid pixelized figures you should obtain a higher resolution `Depth.jpg` image. As far as I know you can not make a pixelized jpg image look better with tikz. You can draw another image in tikz, but you can not just simply convert jpg to tikz.

Comment: The `\pgfdeclareimage` understands the option `interpolate=true` and the PDF viewer renders it according to this option. If you you want to use a PGF image you need to use `\pgftext{\pgfuseimage{<name of image>}}`. (You can also switch from `tikzpicture` to `pgfpicture` then.) But beware, the quality of the image won’t rise, JPGs will always be a raster image format. Be it as it may, you do not get any improvement by using TikZ over `\includegraphics`.

Comment: How can i improve my figure's quality??? i tried to make it .pdf instead of .jpg but it gives the same result.

Comment: @Misaki if your figure is a low quality jpg, it will always stay a low quality image. Doesn't matter which format. Where did you get the `Depth.jpg` image from? If you're exporting it from another program try exporting it at a bigger size.

Comment: There is no real question here: sorry but it's 'unclear' as it stands.